# How do I Find the value of this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$if\quad a,b,c\ \in { Z }^{ + }\quad and \ \ a+b+c=5\quad \\ find\ \ \sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }+25 } +\sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }+16 } \sqrt { { c }^{ 2 }+9 }$$

I've tried many times to solve this problem , but unfortunately I didn't get any solution . I used (Cauchy-Schwarz) in one of my attempts and what I got is $$\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }+25 } +\sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }+16 } \sqrt { { c }^{ 2 }+9 } \ge \frac { 17\sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 }$$ So , I am a little bit confused about the way of dealing with this problem . I hope that you can help me to figure it out .

Comment: You can find only the minimum of this expression. You have done correctly. The question should be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can find all exact solutions for the problem. Just make sure about the notation. I'm assuming that $\Bbb Z^{+}$ do not include $0$.

Once $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z^{+}$ and $a+b+c=5$ then the solutions are:

$$(a,b,c) \in \{(1,1,3),(1,3,1),(3,1,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,1)\}$$

and replacing that in the expression:

$$\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }+25 } +\sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }+16 } \sqrt { { c }^{ 2 }+9 }$$

you will find all soutions.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are positive integers that sum to 5, there are only a few possibilities for $(a, b, c)$, namely

```
3, 1, 1
1, 3, 1
1, 1, 3
2, 2, 1
2, 1, 2
1, 2, 2
```

You can simply compute the value for each of these. One of them will be smallest (or largest). They certainly won't all be the same, which is what the (badly written) problem suggests. The value for the first one is about $5.83$, while for the last it's about $21.22$.